# How to assign event.ptr in epoll?

Tags: c++, c, epoll

```
struct sockitem* NewSockItem(int sockfd, CallBack cb) {

    struct sockitem *si = (struct sockitem*)malloc(sizeof(struct sockitem));
    si->sockfd = sockfd;
    si->callback = cb;
    return si;
}

struct epoll_event ev;
ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;
ev.events.ptr = NewSockItem(clientfd, recv_cb);

epoll_ctl(eventloop->epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, clientfd, &ev);
```

when build, error happens like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dltM4.png)

Comment: Isn't that supposed to be `ev.data.ptr`? Just going by the definition of the `struct` from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html

Comment: You changed the line of code with the error. Now the error message does not fit the code anymore. The error says it is in the line `ev.event.ptr = ...`, but you only have `ev.data.ptr = ...`. What is your current problem?

Comment: use ev.data.ptr , not ev.events.ptr

Comment: For future questions please do not add links to pictures of plain text. Instead just add your text output directly into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ev.data.ptr` instead of `ev.events.ptr`.